# Selenium code working slow for MCQ's option selection

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I was making script for autoclicking mcq's question where all the question are fluctuating in random order and there option are also in fluctuating in random order
so i have all the answer of the question in `list1` and i find that in web page with the help find `find_element` with xpath
so que. is there that my script works fine but it takes lots of time to execute so how i can make it more optimize to work it fast.
    from selenium import webdriver

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(
    'https://www.onlinequizcreator.com/lock-down-battle-computer-fundamental-till-19/4/2020-11.50-p.m.-only/quiz-445191')

elm = browser.find_element_by_class_name("playbuttons")
elm.click()

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='View my result without account']").click()

def hasxpath(xpath):
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
        return True
    except:
        return False


list1 = ['Assembly languages',
        'Microcomputer',
        '1 and 2',
        'Saga 220',
        'DSL',
        'Arithmetic Logic Unit',
        'The computer and software system that control the machine',
        'Formula Translation',
        'eight binary digits',
        'RISC',
        '1, 2, 3 and 4',
        'OCR',
        'Dot Per Inch',
        'diagnostic software',
        'Both 1 and 2']

browser.implicitly_wait(10)
k=0
while (k==15):
    for i in list1:
        if hasxpath("//*[@id='questioncontainer']/fieldset[1]/ul[1]//span[text()='{}']".format(i))==True:
            list1.remove(i)
            k=k+1
            print(k)
            break
```

so here value comes from list1 and goes in xpath

Comment: From the script you have given me, the code does not function. One reason it might be taking long is you check for each answer in your list against the xpath. You should get the xpath question text, and look that up in a dictionary you have, where the key is the question, and the value is the answer. Then you can click the answer.

Comment: Try using `BeautifulSoup` along with `selenium`. Also use `ID's` or `css selectors` instead of `XPATHS`. It will work super fast then. This is because `XPATHS` are the **slowest locators** present. I guarentee you using `BeautifulSoup` with `selenium` will work like charm...